# ebay api filter listing on the basis of current date

Tags: php, html, cakephp

want to filter the listing on the basis of current date. so i can only get data added on current date.

i tried the below with StartTimeFrom, but nothing changed, it is showing all the records.

$resp = simplexml_load_file("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=APIKEY&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD=true&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=200&categoryId=9801&siteid=3&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&DetailName=ItemSpecificDetails&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&sortOrder=StartTimeNewest&itemFilter(0).name=ListingType&itemFilter(0).value(0)=FixedPrice&itemFilter(0).value(1)=Classified&itemFilter(0).value(2)=StoreInventory&paginationInput.pageNumber=$count");

Comment: The URL shown doesn't include StartTimeFrom.

Comment: not getting the proper way to use StartTimeFrom in my current api

Answer (score 0):

The [eBay documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/types/ItemFilterType.html) indicates that StartTimeFrom is a `dateTime` field. Their [documentation of dateTime](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/types/simpleTypes.html#dateTime) says that it's an ISO8601 formatted date. PHP's [date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) indicates that 'c' is the format character to get an ISO8601 time.

So, just add `$start_string = date('c', $start_time);` where `$start_time` is assumed to be the UNIX timestamp of the desired start time (which you can get from [PHP's strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [MySQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), for example), and then insert `&itemFilter(1).name=StartTimeFrom&itemFilter(1).value=$start_string` into your URL.

Comment: used it like this in my url :-                                                                                                               itemFilter(1).name=StartTimeFrom&itemFilter(1).value=2019-01-17T05:00:00.000Z                                   but it is giving me the extra results with the actual results, please help

Comment: Hopefully someone that's used this particular feature can help you sort that out.